# Numbering a file and copy files ends with a specific digit

Tags: vba, batch-file

I need to copy a file i already created (a.txt) and copy it so i will have
a1.txt
a2.txt
a3.txt
etc.
until i get a999999.txt
then, copy the files that ends with "3", for example a4453.txt to a different folder.

What is the best way to do it? vb/batch file preferred.

Thanks =]
Daniel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off

set "different_folder=c:\diff"


for /l %%n in (1;1;999999) do (
  copy "a.txt" "a%%n.txt"
)

for /f %%f in ('dir /b a*.txt ^| findstr /i /e "3.txt"') do (
  copy "%%~ff" %different_folder%
)
```

Not tested.